# Introduce test suit class to Maven pom file

Tags: maven, testing, junit

Is there anyway to introduce my test suit class to maven in pom.xml? currently maven run my test classes without order but I want to run them with specific order and configuration which has been defined in my testsuit class
Thank you

Comment: Are we talking about unit tests ? If yes than it does not make sense, cause unit tests must be independat without any order in it. Apart from that what are you using TestNG, JUnit ?

Comment: I solve my problem with introducing my test suite class in pom.xml and control test flow in test suit class.  <includes>
                        <include>**/TotalTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>